# Python :: How to split a xml string by tag?

Tags: python, xml

I have a string (in a file called token.txt) with the following text.

```
<nexttoken>test1</nexttoken>
<nexttoken>test2</nexttoken>
```

I want to remove the tags `<nexttoken>` and I want to display the second line i.e. `test2`

Output = test2

**What I tried:**

```
with open("token.txt") as f:   
        for line in f:
            if "nexttoken" in line: 
                lines_contain_next_token = line 
                n2=lines_contain_next_token.replace("</nexttoken>","\n")
                n3=n2.replace("<nexttoken>","\n")
                n4=n3.replace("\n",",")
                n5=n4.replace(' ','')
                print n5
```

Comment: Why not just parse this as XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just two `nexttoken` tags in your text then you can use regex to extract the required value.

**Ex:**

```
import re
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    data = infile.read()
c = re.findall("\<nexttoken\>(.*)\<\/nexttoken\>", data)
print(c[1])
```

**Output:**

```
test2
```

**Note:** If your src file is an XML file i highly suggest you use a python xml parser.